# Grep for a string in file without using pipe

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, tail

I want to grep for a word in a file in the last n lines without using the pipe.

```
grep <string> filename
```

enables to search the filename for a string.  But, I want to search for a string in the last N lines of the file. Any command to search for that without using the pipe?

Comment: Why are you avoiding pipes? IPC is core to the UNIX philosophy of not cramping all the functionality into monolithic programs and having small, specialized programs communicate instead.

Comment: How about `tail -50 filename > filename2 && grep <string> filename2`? No pipes and last 50 lines.

Comment: lol, very good. Another idea is `sed -n "$n,\$/srchTarg/p" file`. where $n would bet to set the first line of a range expression for searching. Good luck.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the pipe for some specific reason? Is that actually the goal or is something else the ultimate goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Process Substitution to search string only in last 5 lines:

```
grep string <(tail -n 5 filename)
```

Comment: Alas process substitution is implemented in the shell as pipes. We need purity here!!!

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, the shell command:

```
ed input <<EOF
$
1,-50d
v/pattern/d
w output
q
EOF
```

would work. With the added advantage that error indications are only one character `?` for brevity. Of course you'd have to change the HERE document depending on how many tail lines you want (-50), the pattern, and the input and output filenames every time your arguments change. And you kinda have to have a machine that still runs `ed` but at least you won't have to use a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Awk script which finds all matches, but eventually prints only the ones which are within 50 lines from the end of the file.

```
awk -v pattern='foo' -v limit=50 '$0 ~ pattern { a[NR]=$0 }
    END { for (n in a) if (n >= NR-limit) print a[n] }' file
```

The array `a` stores each match with its line number as the key; in the `END` loop, we print the array elements whose key is within the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl oneliner:

```
perl -0777 -wlnE 'my @all = split("\n",$_); my $t = scalar @all; for my $l(@all[$t-50 .. $t]) {print $l if $l =~ /word/;} filename'
```

Comment: What's with the big slurp?  The `sed` solution posted in a comment by shellter does this much more elegantly.  You could use the same logic in Perl if you prefer, and factor in the calculation of `n`.